# Naming abstract classes and Interfaces in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, typescript, naming-conventions

There are debates and no consistency in this question, so I want to clarify naming standards for class, file names, suffixes and others for typescript.
I want to know, how you name abstract classes, interfaces and logically organize code in your Typescript projects?

**Possible solutions:**

For interfaces:

- with "I" as a prefix
- with "Interface" as a suffix
- with nothing added at all

For abstract classes:

- with "Abstract" as prefix
- something like "Base" as a prefix
- with nothing at all

Example with C#

```
public class User : AbstractUser, IUser
```

Same in Java and PHP

```
public class User extends AbstractUser implements UserInterface
```

And in Typescript

```
export class User extends AbstractUser implements UserInterface
```

This is the normal approach used in frameworks based on languages such as C#, Java and modern PHP7+

---

Microsoft is recommending add "Interface" as a suffix, which for me is correct.
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Interfaces.md#class-types

Another popular style guide is suggesting not to add any suffixes for prefixes to interfaces, for me violates the rules, readability and overall looks wrong. https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/styleguide/styleguide.html#interface

```
export class User extends AbstractUser implements User
```

Answer (score 4):

I think this is a matter of taste.

I'd use interface name `User` instead of `IUser` or `UserInterface` *if* a user object can be described by plain JSON, thus being a pure data object with no class-like behavior. Because you might never need an implementing class, you can always use object literals:

```js
interface User {
    name: string;
    email: string;
}

function createDummyUser(): User {
    return {
        name : "Alice",
        email: "a@wonder.land"
    }
}
```

I'd use the plain name of the abstract class of objects (like 'Car') and use a specific name for the non-abstract class (like 'Beetle'). You can ensure your abstract implementation is not used by mistake by making the constructor protected:

```
class Car {
    protected constructor() {
    }
}

const fail = new Car();  // error because c'tor is protected

class Beetle extends Car {
       public constructor(){
           super();
       }
}

let itBe = new Beetle();  // here we go!
```

Answer (score 1):

Our node app is demanding on interfaces a lot - they everywhere, we  do the type checking and type hinting, so meaningful names are super important for us.

```
import {MediaInterface} from 'app/models/mediaInterface';
import {ServerInterface} from 'app/server/serverInterface';
import {UserInterface} from 'app/models/userInterface';

export class MediaStorage extends AbstractStorage implements StorageInterface {

  /**
   * current user
   * @private
   */
  private user: UserInterface;

  /**
   * @constructor
   * @param {ServerInterface} app
   */
  constructor(private app: ServerInterface) {
    // ...
  }

  /**
   * @param {UserInterface} user
   * @returns {Promise<any>}
   */
  public deleteUserMedia(user: UserInterface): Promise<any> {
    // ...
  }

  /**
   * @param {object} req request
   * @param {object} res response
   * @returns {Promise<MediaInterface>}
   */
  public create(req: any, res: any): Promise<MediaInterface> {
     // ...
  }

}
```